# single back option for two different action pages

Tags: back

i have Two view pages.one is invoice*list and another is invoicenew..both are linked to final page called invoiceprint.rhtml page..now if i want to go to back to print page how can i go..if i opened printpage through lnvoicelist then back button should work for invoice list page and if i opened print page through invoice*new page then back button should work for invoice_new page..how can i give?

```
<div align = 'left'>
  <%= link_to "Back"%>
  <% if params[:from] == "invoice_new"%>
    <%= link_to "Back", :action => "invoice_new" %>
  <% elsif params[:from] == "invoice_lists" %>
    <%= link_to "Back",:action => "invoice_lists" %>
  <% end%>

</div>
```